# flutter http POST to google cloud function always returns 415

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform

I try to call a google cloud function from flutter using POST, but it always returns 415.

This is the call:

```dart
    http
        .post(
      Uri.parse('https://example.com/function'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "message": "test",
        "version": "1",
      }),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    )
```

The google cloud function is set up correctly, I can call it successfully with curl

```bash
curl -X POST https://example.com/function --data '{"message": "test", "version": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Edit:
This is the google cloud function:

```py
import functions_framework


# Register an HTTP function with the Functions Framework
@functions_framework.http
def my_http_function(request):
    # Your code here

    print(request)

    # Return an HTTP response
    return "OK"
```

which is deployed like this:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy example-func \
--gen2 \
--runtime=python311 \
--region europe-west3 \
--source=. \
--entry-point=my_http_function \
--trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated
```

As the curl post works, the function seems to work fine and as expected.

Edit 2:

This happens from flutter web. I found some hints, that CORS might be the issue and adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the header would solve it, but it didn't.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should send json and accept json in the header instead:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  "Accept":"application/json",
},
```

Updated: CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I added the charset. Try again. If still not work, let's see the api server config. Is that private or public ? @GenError

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Then it shouldnt be the client error. Let's narrow it to the next target: CORS. I have updated the CORS config. You may check it out the link.

Comment: I added CORS to the flutter request and like this (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors?hl=de#functions_http_cors-python) to the cloud function. I also added `.onError((e) => print(e))` to see what kind of error happens. The error is an `XMLHttpRequest error.`

Comment: From the logs in google cloud I can see the OPTIONS request, which is answered with the 204 and headers as given in the example code I linked in the previous comment.

Comment: What happens if you disable-web-security ? Try `flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"`

Comment: Then the request is successful, so it is in fact something within the CORS configuration that is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```dart
    http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://example.com/function'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      body: {
        "message": "test",
        "version": "1",
      },
    )
```